Recommended books on Dybbuks and Shedim?
What books are suggested for studying the Jewish perspective on dybbuks and shedim? I am looking for books by Jewish Kabbalists/sages outside the Talmud/Zohar. Maybe their individual works.

What do you think about Winkler "Dybbuk" ? https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/dybbuk_gershon-winkler/788455/item/28828529/?mkwid=%7cdc&pcrid=77172150940733&pkw=&pmt=be&slid=&product=28828529&plc=&pgrid=1234751854563929&ptaid=pla-4580771612621121&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping+-+Low+Vol+Scarce+-+%2410+-+%2450&utm_term=&utm_content=%7cdc%7cpcrid%7c77172150940733%7cpkw%7c%7cpmt%7cbe%7cproduct%7c28828529%7cslid%7c%7cpgrid%7c1234751854563929%7cptaid%7cpla-4580771612621121%7c&msclkid=e3f8886dc71e11ca469cee8aafff4f47#idiq=28828529&edition=4459650

Morris Faierstein just published a book "The Dybbuk: Its Origins and History" (SUNY series in Western Esoteric Traditions). It has many refereces which can pont you in the right direction. https://www.amazon.com/Dybbuk-Origins-History-Esoteric-Traditions-ebook/dp/B0CQL8VKXJ/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3HJBZDJ0DDZL9&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.6NjrHxE026NtErPBcq6fSw.5G_p3Iy_bBTMquKsOPWjUXwRLyRKXuhv0DThrobWrQk&dib_tag=se&keywords=The+Dybbuk%3A+Its+Origins+and+History&qid=1726459149&sprefix=the+dybbuk+its+origins+and+history%2Caps%2C120&sr=8-1

Chapter 88 of Minchat Yehuda by Rabbi Yehuda Fetaya, one of the leading Iraqi-Israeli kabbalists of the 19th and 20th centuries CE, deals extensively with dybbuks and shin daleds.
While this is just one chapter of the book, it is 160 pages long, and the rest of the book is certainly worth reading as well.
The edition linked to above is in English translation, which is rather rare for the subject matter.
